how to stop "manage personal info in wallet" in input field in nuxt
In the form fields in nuxt app, when i click input field, it shows a popup and with some suggestion with written as "manage personal info in wallet".
I have tried autocomplete="off" but it is not working.

Where is this coming from? What kind of extension/app do you use? Also, mind sharing a visual screenshot of the popup?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
